# how to filter data from JSON using GSON

Tags: java, api, gson, httprequest

I have this JSON file:

```
{"status":"success","data":[{"id":1,"employee_name":"Tiger Nixon","employee_salary":320800,"employee_age":61,"profile_image":""},{"id":2,"employee_name":"Garrett Winters","employee_salary":170750,"employee_age":63,"profile_image":""},{"id":3,"employee_name":"Ashton Cox","employee_salary":86000,"employee_age":66,"profile_image":""}
```

For reading the "status" my code looks like this and it **WORKS FINE**:

```
JsonObject json = new Gson().fromJson(responseText, JsonObject.class);
System.out.println(json.get("status"));
```

Question: How can I get e.g. the second employee_name (Garrett Winters)?
I have tried out these, but it **DOES NOT WORK** :-(

```
System.out.println(json.get("data.employee_name(2)"));
System.out.println(json.get("data[2].employee_name"));
System.out.println(json.get("data/employee_name(2)"));
System.out.println(json.get("data/employee_name[2]"));
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to chain methods in order to get what you want. For example

```
json.getAsJsonArray("data").get(2).getAsJsonObject().get("employee_name")
```